# Using Modernizr to test browser support for css calc()

Tags: css, modernizr, browser-feature-detection

How can I test if a browsers support the CSS3 calc() property using Modernizr?

I have tried:

```
if (Modernizr.testProp('cssCalc')) {
    console.log('CSS calc() supported');
}
```

but this only returns "*undefined*" in the console.

(I am using modernizr-2.6.2.js).

What is the right way to use Modernizr for browser feature detection?

Comment: `testProp()` takes a CSS _property name_.

Comment: Background on this: Safari 5 (which includes Safari for Windows and Mobile Safari running on IOS 5 doesn't support the CSS value calc() (see http://caniuse.com/calc).  I want to use calc () in my CSS and js for a fallback for browsers that don't support this.

Answer (score 10):

```
if (Modernizr.csscalc) {
  console.log('CSS calc() supported');
}
```

Comment: I get undefined on all browsers. i am guessing modernizr does not include it in its default build?